# The entity "uuml" was referenced, but not declared - XMLStreamException

Tags: java, xml, excel, xml-parsing, stax

Trying to generate **XLSX** file from **SpreadsheetML 2003** (which is basically a XML). Using the CLOB from database, CLOB contains the SpreadsheetML 2003 (XML). I am trying to parse the xml through **STAX** parser, and write it into the XLSX file using **POI API**.But it is throwing below exception while processing in stax.

Note : XML encoding **UTF-8** format is used.

**Exception :**

```
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,16706]
Message: The entity "uuml" was referenced, but not declared.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:588)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.getElementText(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:845)
        at com.db.smis.planus.servlet.ServletApp.doProcess(ServletApp.java:224)
```

**Sample XML:**

```html
  <?xml version="1.0"? encoding="UTF-8">
       <?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
       <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
         xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
         xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
         xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
         xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
        <Row>
          <Cell ss:StyleID="s29"><Data ss:Type="Number">7662</Data></Cell>
          <Cell ss:StyleID="s73"><Data ss:Type="String">C. &amp; A. AAAAA &amp; CO. KG</Data></Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s29"><Data ss:Type="Number">7662</Data></Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s28"><Data ss:Type="String">M&uuml;nchen,K&ouml;ln</Data></Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s29"><Data ss:Type="Number">7662</Data></Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s28"><Data ss:Type="String">D&uuml;sseldorf</Data></Cell>
    </Row>
    </Workbook>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `&uuml;` entitie, or replace them with a hex or decimal equivalent, in this case i guess [`ü`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9C):

```
<!DOCTYPE definition [
    <!ENTITY uuml "&#220;">
]>
```

**UPDATE**
If you have more special characters, use our Apache commons lang’s friends [`StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXML`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeXml%28java.lang.String%29).

[Full example here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.es/2012/09/how-to-replace-escape-xml-special-characters-java-string.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I cannot assure only this kind of character will come in the XML. May be some other special/foreign character also come. Then I need to define all the entities in DTD ?

Comment: Any other alternative way to fix this issue ?

Comment: you must parse/replace the special characters... [Googling a bit](https://www.google.es/search?q=xml+parse+%26uuml%3B+characters&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=jLyvVYSHCsvt-AHY-4GgCw#q=xml+replace+special+characters+java) does not seem [hard to find for `Java`](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.es/2012/09/how-to-replace-escape-xml-special-characters-java-string.html)